# The size of input tag doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code below is like a chat program . There is text input at the buttom of the page.but when i change the size it doesn't change . i uses style="width: XXpx" too but again no change .

```
     <script>
          function updatePageMsg() {

     var msg = document.getElementById("Text").value;
     var divElement = document.createElement("div");
     divElement.setAttribute("style", "background-size:cover; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px");
     var pElement = document.createElement("p");
     pElement.innerHTML = msg;
     divElement.appendChild(pElement);
     rightDiv = document.getElementById("rightdiv");
     rightDiv.appendChild(divElement);
     document.getElementById("Text").value = null;
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Text').keypress(function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 13) {
             $('#SendBtn').click();
             return false;
         }
     });
 });
  </script>

 <div style="margin-top: 50px; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0">

  <div style="width: 30%; left: 0; height: 100%; background-color: yellow; float: left; overflow: scroll"></div>
  <div id="rightdiv" style="width: 70%; right: 0; height: 100%; background-color: red; float: left; overflow: scroll"></div>
   </div>

    <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 3px; width: 100%; background-size: cover; left: 0; text-align: center">
   <div>
   <input id="Text" type="search" value="Enter your Message here" style="font-size: 20px" size="100" />

   <input onclick="updatePageMsg(); return false;" id="SendBtn" type="button" value="Send" style="font-size: 20px; bottom: 6px" />

   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Changes as expected for me, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkyqgh9k/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input id="Text" type="search" value="Enter your Message here" style="font-size: 20px" size="100" />
```

To modify the width of the `input` tag you must set `width` property in `style`.

```
   <input id="Text" type="search" placeholder="Enter your Message here" value="" style="font-size: 20px; width : 200px;" />
```

Else reduce the `size` to lesser value. As the size is `100`, it's looking big.

```
   <input id="Text" type="search" value="Enter your Message here" style="font-size: 20px" size="40" />
```

Just one  more correction I've made. The message "Enter your message here" must be placeholder and not value. If you set it in value then the user need to delete the text manually before entering some data.

Comment: you are right.. in jsfiddle everythings go correct but when i run in chrome it doesn't change . i corrected the overlapping .actually it just work for under 100px

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have some CSS overlapping here. Your code without any additional CSS files works perfectly as you might find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/webyourway/bsu7d9mn/2/

I have just added "width: 200px;" in style attribute and it worked.

```
<input id="Text" type="search" value="Enter your Message here" style="font-size: 20px;width: 200px;" size="100" />
```

I believe you should check CSS for this element. Also size 100 is quite big and it is better to change it to some lesser value.

Comment: you are right.. in jsfiddle everythings go correct but when i run in chrome it doesn't change . i corrected the overlapping .actually it just work for under 100px

Comment: Do you have this page live so that I could look into?

Answer (score 0):

When set input size using style there no more need to **size** attribute.

```
   <input id="Text" type="search" value="Enter your Message here" style="font-size: 20px;width:100px">
```

Comment: you are right.. in jsfiddle everythings go correct but when i run in chrome it doesn't change . i corrected the overlapping .actually it just work for under 100px